# Parsing options that take arguments in getopts

Tags: bash, getopts

I have the following program `foo`, that can take one of three optional flags, `f`, `g`, or `s`:

```
usage()
{
    echo "Use this correctly"
}

while getopts "fgs" opt; do
    case $opt in
        f)
          echo f
          foo="$OPTARG"
          echo $foo
          ;;  
        g) 
          echo g 
          foo="g"
          ;;  
        s)  
          echo s
          foo="s"
          ;;  
    esac
done

if [ -z "$foo" ]
then
   usage
   exit
fi

echo $foo
exit
```

When I do `foo -g` or `foo -s` I get the expected outputs:

```
g
g
```

and

```
s
s
```

respectively. But when I do `foo -f bar` I expect

```
f
bar
bar
```

but get

```
f
Use this correctly
```

indicating that `$foo` is not being set properly in the `-f` case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace

```
while getopts "fgs" opt; do
```

with

```
while getopts "f:gs" opt; do
```

Options that take an argument must be followed by a colon. Only for these options, `getopts` sets the `OPTARG` variable.